# Why can't I get Environ variables within a Flask script?

Tags: python, flask, environment-variables

I have this script:

```
import os
secret = os.environ.get('MFS')
print(secret)
```

For some reason, it returns `None`. I set that environment variable to a secret key that I want to use to set `app.config['SECRET_KEY']`. But, if I run this command: `python3 -c 'import os;print(os.environ.get("MFS"))'`, it returns the correct environment variable. It doesn't matter if I cd to the project folder and run that or not, it just works. Even though I am using a venv to run the Flask app, that command still works when I run the venv Python. Why is this happening?

Comment: How do you run the flask app? From pycharm?

Comment: Environment variables are inherited from your parent process; it gets environment variables from _its_ parent process. So if you're using an IDE to run your Python interpreter (making that IDE the interpreter's parent), it may not have environment variables from your shell if you don't start that IDE *from your shell*.

Comment: (This is common to _all_ software; it's not something specific to Flask, or to Python at all).

Comment: I am primarily using atom (with a shebang line and the scripts plugin) but have also ran it from the terminal. I have also created another test file in the same directory with the same code (but on multiple lines) of the quick 2 line script, and it works when I run it the same way as the Flask script.